# Options for private access to a staging website

Tags: django, networking, web, staging

What options do I have to put a website on a staging server and to allow the access only to specific people plus several external services, like PayPal IPN, Facebook Connect, Twitter OAuth2, Google OAuth2, etc.

Let's say, I have full control of the server with Debian Linux and can install any software necessary or add any configuration.

The website is running on Django.

I would like to let specific people test the website as both - anonymous users and logged in users.

Comment: Hm, all I can say is that you want to remove all social authentication from your web application, because you want the full control over it, second you will create users in `django-admin` and pass the `username` and `password` privately, and that is it.

Comment: In such situations I am usually using Basic Authentication on top of normal Django authentication, so that both - the anonymous and authenticated - views could be checked. But in the case of external services, I am not 100% sure how to deal with that.